Add array values to combo boxes via function - Winforms C#
im trying to systematically assign Baud rate options to 4 different combo boxes, but i dont want to hard code it like i currently am.
CURRENT SOLUTION:
baudBox3.Items.Add(9600);
baudBox3.Items.Add(19200);
baudBox3.Items.Add(38400);
baudBox3.Items.Add(57600);
baudBox3.SelectedItem = 9600;

I'd prefer to have a function i could pass the values of an array into with the combobox i want to update like so, but it can't get it to work properly.
int[] baud = { 9600, 19200, 38400, 57600 };
baudBox3.Click += AddToCombo(baud, baudBox3);

public void AddToCombo(Array array, ComboBox c)
{
    foreach (var a in array)
    {
        c.Items.Add(a);
    }
}

If it makes more sense to just hard code in the baud values, then i'll do that instead.

You may consider reading Handle and raise events.

Why not baudBox.DataSource = baud;, where baud is your int array?

Also, in your event handler you add these elements whenever you click the combo box. But maybe that's not what you would like to do.

If you want to run this on click, control event handlers have to follow a specific signature. The click event signature looks like this:
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)

The EventArgs does not have space for your baud array. There are two solutions here: one is to inherit a new class from EventArgs with a property for your array, and use that. But that's overkill. The other is to just reference the array as a member of the form's class. Let's go with that for now.
(But if you did want to use EventArgs, the type would be int[], rather than the Array used with the method in the question).
So now we have this:
int[] baud = { 9600, 19200, 38400, 57600 };
baudBox3.Click += AddToCombo;

private void AddToCombo(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var cb = sender as ComboBox;
    cb.Items.Clear();
    foreach (var b in baud)
    {
        cb.Items.Add(b);
    }
}

Or even better:
int[] baud = { 9600, 19200, 38400, 57600 };
baudBox3.Click += AddToCombo;

private void AddToCombo(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var cb = sender as ComboBox;
    cb.Items.Clear(); 
    cb.Items.AddRange(baud);
}

But also, we need more details on what you mean by "not work properly". In what way? What behavior do you see instead?
Finally, this won't run until someone does a click action on the box, and not every mouse-down action is a formal "click". Are you sure this shouldn't just run when the form loads? You can do it with just one line in the Form_Load event:
baudBox3.Items.AddRange(new int[] {9600, 19200, 38400, 57600 });


this is all very useful, thank you! and you're very right, it should only need to be called when i load the form.  How would the function call look within FormLoad?

@RobbieSchertz It's a one-liner: baudBox3.Items.AddRange(new int[] {9600, 19200, 38400, 57600 });

You should use data binding and the ComboBox.DataSource property to directly assign an array or list to your combo box items.
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {

        comboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += (s, ev) =>
        {
            label2.Text = $"{comboBox1.SelectedValue} baud selected.";
        };
        comboBox1.DataSource = new [] { 9600, 19200, 38400, 57600 };

    }

    public int[] BaudRates { get => comboBox1.DataSource as int[]; }
}


